# Starting first job causes - Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel exception when declared multiple DirectChannels

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-integration

I have a Spring Batch application which is successfully running spring batch jobs but i have exception when declaring multiple DirectChannels.

The exception happens when i start the "firstJob". Here is the exception:

```
`Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'IFRSGoodBookService-1.secondReplies'.
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:76)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.sendInternal(AbstractMessageChannel.java:375)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.sendWithMetrics(AbstractMessageChannel.java:346)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:326)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:499)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.doProduceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:354)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:283)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:247)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:142)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.doHandleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleWithMetrics(AbstractMessageHandler.java:90)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:70)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.sendInternal(AbstractMessageChannel.java:375)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.sendWithMetrics(AbstractMessageChannel.java:346)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:326)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:299)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.lambda$sendMessage$1(MessageProducerSupport.java:262)
    at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.lambda$observe$0(Observation.java:493)
    at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.observeWithContext(Observation.java:603)
    at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.observe(Observation.java:492)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.access$200(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.createAndSend(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:397)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.onMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:360)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1663)
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:139)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    ... 50 common frames omitted`
```

This is my FlowConfig class which declares the channels:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class FlowConfig {

    private final QueueConfig queueConfig;

    @Bean
    public DirectChannel firstRequests() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectChannel firstReplies() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectChannel secondRequests() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectChannel secondReplies() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean("secondManagerInBoundFlow")
    @Profile("manager")
    public IntegrationFlow secondManagerInBoundFlow() {
        return queueConfig.getInboundAdapter(true, secondReplies());
    }

    @Bean("secondWorkerInBoundFlow")
    @Profile("worker")
    public IntegrationFlow secondInBoundFlow() {
        return queueConfig.getInboundAdapter(false, secondRequests());
    }

    @Bean("secondManagerOutboundFlow")
    @Profile("manager")
    public IntegrationFlow secondManagerOutboundFlow() {
        return queueConfig.getOutboundAdapter(true, secondRequests());
    }

    @Bean("secondWorkerOutboundFlow")
    @Profile("worker")
    public IntegrationFlow secondWorkerOutboundFlow() {
        return queueConfig.getOutboundAdapter(false, secondReplies());
    }
    
    @Bean("firstManagerInBoundFlow")
    @Profile("manager")
    public IntegrationFlow firstManagerInBoundFlow() {
        return queueConfig.getInboundAdapter(true, firstReplies());
    }

    @Bean("firstWorkerInBoundFlow")
    @Profile("worker")
    public IntegrationFlow firstWorkerInBoundFlow() {
        return queueConfig.getInboundAdapter(false, firstRequests());
    }

    @Bean("firstManagerOutboundFlow")
    @Profile("manager")
    public IntegrationFlow firstManagerOutboundFlow() {
        return queueConfig.getOutboundAdapter(true, firstRequests());
    }

    @Bean("firstWorkerOutboundFlow")
    @Profile("worker")
    public IntegrationFlow firstWorkerOutboundFlow() {
        return queueConfig.getOutboundAdapter(false, firstReplies());
    }
}
```

This is the implementation of the inbound and outbound adapters:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty("spring.rabbitmq.enabled")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RabbitMqQueueConfig implements QueueConfig {

    private final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
    private final RabbitTemplate defaultRabbitTemplate;
    private final QueueConstants queueConstants;

    @Override
    public IntegrationFlow getInboundAdapter(boolean isManager, DirectChannel channel) {
        String queueName = isManager ? queueConstants.getConstantWithPrefix(QueueConstants.JOB_REPLIES_QUEUE)
                : queueConstants.getConstantWithPrefix(QueueConstants.JOB_REQUESTS_QUEUE);
        return IntegrationFlow.from(Amqp.inboundAdapter(connectionFactory, queueName)).channel(channel).get();
    }

    @Override
    public IntegrationFlow getOutboundAdapter(boolean isManager, DirectChannel channel) {
        String queueName = isManager ? queueConstants.getConstantWithPrefix(QueueConstants.JOB_REQUESTS_QUEUE)
                : queueConstants.getConstantWithPrefix(QueueConstants.JOB_REPLIES_QUEUE);
        AmqpOutboundChannelAdapterSpec messageHandlerSpec = Amqp.outboundAdapter(defaultRabbitTemplate).routingKey(queueName);
        return IntegrationFlow.from(channel).handle(messageHandlerSpec).get();
    }
}
```

This is JobManagerConfiguration

```
@Configuration
@Profile("manager")
@EnableBatchIntegration
@AllArgsConstructor
public class JobManagerPartitionConfiguration {

    private final JobRepository jobRepository;
    private final RemotePartitioningManagerStepBuilderFactory managerStepBuilderFactory;
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;
    private DeleteDataTasklet deleteDataTasklet;
    private InstDataLoader instDataLoader;
    private final ApplicationProperties appProperties;
    private final DirectChannel firstRequests;
    private final DirectChannel firstReplies;
    private final DirectChannel secondRequests;
    private final DirectChannel secondReplies;
    private final ManagerJobListener managerJobListener;
    private final IdBoundaryPartitioner idBoundaryPartitioner;
    private final ContextService contextService;

    @Bean
    public Step firstJobManagerStep() {
        return managerStepBuilderFactory.get("firstJobManagerStep")
                .partitioner("remotefirstJobAsStep", idBoundaryPartitioner)
                .gridSize(appProperties.getJobParameters().getGridSize())
                .outputChannel(firstRequests)
                .inputChannel(firstReplies)
                .listener(new SyncStepContextWithJob())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step secondJobManagerStep() {
        return managerStepBuilderFactory.get("secondJobManagerStep")
                .partitioner("remoteSecondJobAsStep", idBoundaryPartitioner)
                .gridSize(appProperties.getJobParameters().getGridSize())
                .outputChannel(secondRequests)
                .inputChannel(secondReplies)
                .listener(new SyncStepContextWithJob())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job secondJob(Step secondJobManagerStep) {
        return new JobBuilder("secondJob", jobRepository).incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(instDataLoaderStep())
                .next(deleteTable())
                .next(secodJobManagerStep)
                .listener(contextService)
                .listener(managerJobListener)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job firstJob(Step firstJobManagerStep) {
        return new JobBuilder("firstJob", jobRepository).incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(instDataLoaderStep())
                .next(deleteTable())
                .next(firstJobManagerStep)
                .listener(contextService)
                .listener(managerJobListener)
                .build();
    }
```

This is my JobWorkerConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("worker")
@EnableBatchIntegration
@AllArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class JobWorkerPartitionConfiguration {

    private RemotePartitioningWorkerStepBuilderFactory workerStepBuilderFactory;
    private JobRepository jobRepository;
    private JobCache<I9Data[]> cache;
    private CacheJobListener<I9Data[]> jobListener;
    private WorkerJobListener workerJobListener;
    private StepMonitoringListener monitoringListener;
    private ApplicationProperties appProperties;
    private InstDataLoader instDataLoader;
    private ContractLoader contractLoader;
    private CacheItemWriter cacheItemWriter;
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;
    private InstDataJpaCache instDataJpaCache;
    private ContextService contextService;
    private MonitorService monitorService;


    @Bean
    @StepScope
    Job remoteFirstJob(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        return new JobBuilder("remoteFirstJob", jobRepository).start(instDataLoaderStep())
                .next(contractLoaderTaskletStep())
                .next(calculateStep())
                .listener(contextService)
                .listener(jobListener)
                .listener(workerJobListener)
                .listener(monitoringListener)
                // .listener(new SyncStepContextWithJob(this.monitorService))
                .build();
    }

    

    @Bean
    public Step remoteFirstJobAsStep(
            DirectChannel firstRequests,
            DirectChannel firstReplies

    ) {
        return workerStepBuilderFactory.get("remoteFirstJobAsStep")
                .inputChannel(firstRequests)
                .outputChannel(firstReplies)
                .parametersExtractor(remoteJobParametersExtractor())
                .listener(new SyncStepContextWithJob())
                .build();
    }
```

The thing is why it's getting such kind of exception when I am starting the first job. It should not care about the secondReplies as my examples in the JobManagerPartitionConfiguration class there is defined for the firstJob inputChannel = "firstReplies" and outputChannel = "firstRequests" so that mean it should use these channels not the second channel configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Your stack trace clearly indicates that the problem on this channel comes from a consumed message via AMQP Inbound Channel Adapter:

```
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:262)
at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.access$200(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:69)
at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.createAndSend(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:397)
at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.onMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:360)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1663)
```

Yes, I see that you do like this:

```
@Bean("secondManagerInBoundFlow")
@Profile("manager")
public IntegrationFlow secondManagerInBoundFlow() {
    return queueConfig.getInboundAdapter(true, secondReplies());
}
```

But apparently there is still some active `manager` profile, which makes this channel adapter to be started, but then in this manager profile you probably don't have a consumer for this channel. And that we indeed can see in your code:

```
@Bean("secondWorkerOutboundFlow")
@Profile("worker")
public IntegrationFlow secondWorkerOutboundFlow() {
    return queueConfig.getOutboundAdapter(false, secondReplies());
}
```

Which one looks like for the `worker` profile.

I don't have an answer for your problem since I cannot understand the logic yet.

Comment: The idea is when we are starting the manager and the worker instances of the application to continue "working" the job in the worker instance( something like transfering the work to the worker). Thats why we use actually channels. We have two instances running which job splittid his "work". Also if I remove the secondChannel's everything works as expected.

Comment: As I said, you start that `secondManagerInBoundFlow`, but no one is subscribed to that `secondReplies` in case of only `manager` profile. You probably need to rethink your `secondWorkerOutboundFlow` role. That's only the one which is a subscriber to that channel, so not clear why it out of `manager` profile.

Comment: But why then it throws such an exception when i am starting the firstJob. Doesn't that mean that it should take only the firstRequest and firstReplies and ignore the secondRequest and secondReplies because they are used in the secondJob ?

Comment: Because you start that `secondManagerInBoundFlow` and there is no subscriber for that `secondReplies` channel. That is exactly what we see in your stack trace.

Comment: Yes that’s true. But this channel is not used when a firstJob is started and still is searching for subscriber, because maybe somehow the channels are mixed up and its taking the channels for the secondJob(which channels i do not make a subscriber), that is what i do not want to happen. i want firstJob to use his channels(firstRequest and firstReplies) and secondJob(secondRequest and secondReplies) without carrying other job(s) doesn't have subscriber.